# How to prove that the language of words ucv with as many a's in u as b's in v is irregular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to prove that:
 $L=\{w\in\{a,b,c\}^*\Big|\#_a(u)=\#_b(v),\ \ w=ucv,\ \ \ u,v\in\{a,b\}^*\}$ is irregular, so I'm trying to use the Pumping Lemma.

This is what I tried so far:
$w=a^ncb^n$, then $|w|\ge n$ and $w\in L$.

By, condition 1 and 2 (of the Lemma) we will get that: $w=xyz$ - such that: $x=a^r,\ y=a^s, \ z=a^{n-r-s}cb^n$. ($r+s\le n,\ s>0$)
Then, by condition 3: for any $i\ge 0$ : $xy^iz\in L$.
We will take $i=0$ then - we will get: $xz=a^ra^{n-r-s}cb^n\in L$.
That's means that: $a^{n-s}cb^n\in L$ - contradict!!

This what I did, but I think that I miss something...
Can you please guide me and tell me where to look at?

Comment: You may be interested in our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular).

Comment: Oh, I saw it! :-) but I'm still thinking that I miss something, I look at my proof and saying to myself "It's too good to be truth". I don't see why this incorrect, but I feel that I miss something at my proof, and this why I wrote this question - because I'd like to get little help :-)